# What remove inline style to css file

Tags: css

I have a problem. When i try to move inline style to css file l write this code .

```
#slider1_container{
position:relative;
top:0px;
left:0px;
Width:600px;
height:300px;
overflow:hidden;
}
#slider1_container.load{
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:0px;
}
#slider1_container. load .f{
filter:alfa(opacity=70)
opacity:0.7;
position:absolute;
display:block;
background-color:#000000;
top;0px;
left:0px;
width:100%;
height:100%,
}
#slider1_container.load .p{
position:absolute;
display:block;
top:0px;
left:0px;
width :100%;
height:100%;
Background:url(../img/loading.gif               
no-repeat center center 
}
```

But when  i move tag slides, slideshow dosn't work 
I want know what do i move div slides to file css. can you help me.
Thanks

Comment: Pay attention when you import your css file. Maybe the slide js script is invoked before or later and it needs this css to work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you including the CSS file correctly within your page?

with the CSS above you're missing a closing brace from the background image url and you're also using a capitalized "Background" which is incorrect.

```
background:url(../img/loading.gif) no-repeat center center;
```

Also where is your css and image "loading.gif" located?

Comment: I correct  write background  with in my file. I copy this url and paste to my file

Comment: I don't know move styles determinate for tag <div u =" slides">